# Dynamic switching between Ethernet and Wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, ethernet

At my university, or specifically in my dorm, Ethernet speed is a sluggish 10 Mb/s. Wifi, on the other hand, is as much as 100 Mb/s if you have a good antenna - I do not, so speeds range from 50 Mb/s to nothing.

Is there a way to configure my networking such that I use wireless until its speed is less than that of the ethernet, and automatically switch over?

```
uname -a
Linux jack-r4 3.5.0-27-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 19:33:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```